# Can same Open graph tags be used for both linkedIn and facebook in the same page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm using `Open graph` tags for sharing URL to both linked in & Facebook. On localhost when I test using LinkedIn inspector tool and Facebook debugger tool. Both are working fine and give no error in the inspector or debugger tools. I'm using `ngrok` to test locally. But when I check in the live site both are not working:

**linkedIn inspector tool result**

[image]

**Facebook debugger result**

[image]

**Meta tags**

```
<!-- Meta tags for facebook & linkedIn-->
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Certificate of Completion" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="&nbsp;" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
    <meta name="author" content="abc">
```

The site uses `https`. So can any one correct me what's wrong with these tags or what needs to be added ?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't give us the URL that Facebook say it has problem with downloading. How do you expect us to help?

Comment: @WizKid `https://staging-courses.drberg.com/certificate/?course_id=670&id=1`

Comment: `https://staging-courses.drberg.com/certificate/?course_id=670&id=1` is the HTML page. Why does it have the og:url of the image? og:url should point to the HTML page. og:image:secure_url should point to the image

Comment: Thanks @WizKid. If that's the case then why it worked fine Locally with me?